# Is there a way to store these user defined functions in an external file?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, user-defined-functions, file-handling

i'm a relatively new programmer and i'm working on a university project, I want to be able to use file handling to store some of my work outside of the code but I'm not really too sure how, Preferably I'd want to store my user defined functions in a file but i'm not too sure how to go about doing that or if it's even possible at all.

The code i'd like to store externally is as follows:

```
#This is my combat module, I Call on this every time the user enters combat
def combat():
    print("""To defeat the enemy you must hit a higher number than them, if the enemy hits higher you die""")
    player_damage = random.randrange(7,15)
    print("\nYou hit for: ", player_damage)
    enemy_damage = random.randrange(1, 10)
    print("The enemy hit for: ", enemy_damage)

    if player_damage > enemy_damage:
        print("\nYou successfully defeated the enemy")
    elif enemy_damage  > player_damage:
        print("\nThe enemy strikes a fatal blow and you die almost instantly")
        GameOver()

#Game Over function
def GameOver():
    #Plays everytime the user dies
    print("This is the end of your journey, thanks for playing.")
    input("\nPress enter to exit")

#A simple fuction for when the user needs to choose yes or no
def YesNo():
    while True:
        answer = input("(y/n): ")
        if answer in ('y', 'n'):
            break
        print("Invalid input.")
    if answer == 'y':
        return True
    else:
        return False

#Displays the logo
def welcome():
    #Introduce the game to the player
    print("Welcome to:")
    print("""
  _______ _             _____                 
 |__   __| |           / ____|                
    | |  | |__   ___  | |     __ ___   _____  
    | |  | '_ \ / _ \ | |    / _` \ \ / / _ \ 
    | |  | | | |  __/ | |___| (_| |\ V /  __/ 
    |_|  |_| |_|\___|  \_____\__,_| \_/ \___| 
                      / _|                    
                 ___ | |_                     
                / _ \|  _|                    
               | (_) | |                      
     __  __     \___/|_|           _          
    |  \/  |         | |          (_)         
    | \  / |_   _ ___| |_ ___ _ __ _  __ _    
    | |\/| | | | / __| __/ _ \ '__| |/ _` |   
    | |  | | |_| \__ \ ||  __/ |  | | (_| |   
    |_|  |_|\__, |___/\__\___|_|  |_|\__,_|   
             __/ |                   (v1.0)   
            |___/                           """)
```

Comment: Of course you can, that is what imports do, `from your_py import whatever`. Just make sure your .py is in your pythonnpath

Comment: @Padraic-Cunningham Would you care to explain how I do that though please, as I say i'm new to this sorry.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 and Python 3.5.0

Comment: Check this out https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html  and https://www.hackthissite.org/articles/read/1056 and http://www.learnpython.org/en/Modules_and_Packages, any one of those will have you writing modules in 5 minutes

Comment: And http://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10 will show you how to set your PYTHONPATH, i have a folder called `/home/padraic/my_mods` where I store all my own custom modules, the directory is in my PYTHONPATH so I can import them from anywhere

Comment: @Padraic-Cunningham That works perfectly, Thanks an absolute boatload! I wish i would've known that the official documentation was actually useful!

Comment: no worries, the python docs are actually very good and generally easy to understand, if you are writing  python on windows I would recommend three things,cygwin  https://www.cygwin.com/ pycharm community edition https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/ and the excellent ipython http://ipython.org/. You should also get familiar with pip http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/